# A and B be sets. Show the inclusion is strict in $int(A) \cup int(B) \subset int(A \cup B)$

Tags: real-analysis, solution-verification

To show the inclusion is strict in $int(A) \cup int(B) \subset int(A \cup B)$ can we consider the following as an alternative to using a counterexample i.e. $A = \mathbb{Q}$ and $B = \mathbb{R}\setminus\mathbb{Q}$?:

Since the largest open set contained in $A \cup B$ is $int(A \cup B)$ then $int(A \cup B) \subset A \cup B$ but $A \cup B \not\subset int(A) \cup int(B)$ then $int(A \cup B) \not\subset int(A) \cup int(B)$. Therefore the inclusion is strict.

Comment: Why is $A \cup B \nsubseteq \operatorname{Int}(A) \cup \operatorname{Int}(B)$? What happens if $\operatorname{Int}(A) = A$ and the same for $B$?

Comment: It may be helpful to use precise definitions such as actually showing set containments the usual way by picking an element and use definitions to show it is contained in the larger set.

Comment: Is the inclusion supposed to be strict, or are you disproving that it's necessarily an equality? Let $A$ and $B$ be disjoint and open. Then $int(A)=A$, $int(B)=B$, and $int(A\cup B)=A\cup B$ (I encourage you to prove that last statement as an exercise), so $int(A)\cup int(B)=A\cup B=int(A\cup B)$.

Comment: I am sorry my question was not formulated properly. Thanks to all your comments here it is, better formulated I hope: for any subsets A, B of $\mathbb{R}$, $int(A) \subset A \subset A \cup B$ and $int(B) \subset B \subset A \cup B$ then $int(A) \cup int(B)  \cup A \cup B$ but (largest subset) $int(A \cup B) \subset A \cup B$  so $int(A) \cup int(B) \subset int(A \cup B)$. Question: could the inclusion be proper (i.e. strict)? Consider A the rationals and B the irrationals, $int(A)=int(B)= \phi$; $\phi \subset int(\mathbb{R})= \mathbb{R}$. $ so inclusion proper (strict).

Comment: On 3rd comment above: A and B disjoint and open implies that $A \cup B$ is open. $A \cup B$ is largest subset contained in $A \cup B$ but $int(A \cup B)$ is THE largest subset contained in $A \cup B$ so $int(A \cup B) = A \cup B$ then  $int(A) + int(B) = int(A \cup B)$. In the present case the inclusion is not proper as we have an equality. Can we conclude the inclusion could be proper or be an inclusion with possible equality depending on the characteristics of sets A and B?